# Add Multiple Subdomains In Signing Table And Key Table Opendkim

Tags: postfix, email-server, dkim, opendkim

I need some major help adding multiple subdomains in the signing table and key table for opendkim without listing them one by one.

If I have 50 subdomains I want to add, it will take me forever.

I am sending emails from a subdomain called joe@test.mydomain.com.

Here are my questions:

1. For the etc/opendkim.conf, do I need to add subdomain yes or keep it set to no?
2. For the signing.table file, is it possible to add a wildcard to accommodate for ALL subdomains instead of adding all of them one by one line by line. Will something like this work:
   *@*.mydomain.com default._domainkey.mydomain.com. I have tried that and DKIM always fails unless if I append the subdomain to the selector line as follows: default._domainkey.test.mydomain.com
3. For the key.table file, what do I put?
   default._domainkey.mydomain.com  mydomain.com:default:/etc/opendkim/keys/mydomain.com/default.private

OR

default._domainkey.test.mydomain.com  test.mydomain.com:default:/etc/opendkim/keys/mydomain.com/default.private

Again, if I use the first value it doesnt work. This means if I have 50 subdomains, I need to add each one 50 times on both files.

**How in the heck do third party ESPS like mailchimp, sendgrid, aweber automate this step for thousands if not millions of different clientele domain and subdomain names?**

**If I wanted to be a third party ESP and offer my smtp as a service to send bulk emails, how can I automate the generation of DKIM keys and configuration for multiple clients without having to always add their domains/subdomains in all the files referenced above?**

Answer (score 2):

The DKIM standard does allow for a parent domain to sign messages for sub domains:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6376#section-3.10

> ### 3.10.  Signing by Parent Domains
>
> In some circumstances, it is desirable for a domain to apply a
> signature on behalf of any of its subdomains without the need to
> maintain separate selectors (key records) in each subdomain.
> ...

---

In my `opendkim.conf` I use regular expression file for the SigningTable (`refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable`) to allow wildcard matching and explicitly match all subdomains to the same key as used for the parent domain.

```
*@*.example.com current-key._domainkey.example.com
*@example.com   current-key._domainkey.example.com
```

and then I don't need to maintain unique DKIM keys for each subdomain nor associated unique entries in either KeyTable or SigningTable files.

---

In general, when you need to scale you

- automate your work flows
- you can of course attempt to automate the management of text files
- or attempt to find an automation solution that does not require flat text files.
- Simplify your configuration.

For OpenDKIM for example a lot of things can achieved by using a different back-end than files:

http://www.opendkim.org/opendkim.8.html#DATA%20SETS lists several alternatives :

> Many of the command line and configuration file parameters will refer to a "`dataset`" as their values. This refers to a string that either contains the list of desirable values, or to a file that contains them, or ***(if enabled at compile time) a database containing the data.***
> ...
> **`d)`**  If the string begins with "dsn:" and the OpenDKIM library was compiled to support that database type, then the remainder of the string is a Data Store Name describing the type, location parameters and access credentials for an ODBC or SQL database.
> ...
> For example (all in one line):
>
> ```
> `mysql:://dbuser:dbpass@3306+dbhost/odkim/table=macros?keycol=host?datacol=v1,v2`
> ```
>
> ...
> **`e)`**  If the string begins with "`ldap:`", "`ldaps:`" or "`ldapi:`", it is presumed to be a space-separated set of one or more LDAP URLs that identify a set of servers to be queried.
> ...
> **`f)`** If the string begins with "lua:", it is presumed to refer to a file that contains a Lua script to be executed whenever a query is performed. The key for the query is placed in a global variable called "query", which the called script can then access. The script may return any number of values as required for the type of query being performed.

It should be noted that when you do use such tools instead of a text file or refile dataset in the SigningTable, OpenDKIM will automatically look up entries for the parent domain when no entry for a subdomain is found:

[`man opendking.conf`](http://www.opendkim.org/opendkim.conf.5.html)

> ### `SigningTable (dataset)`
>
> Defines a table used to select one or more signatures to apply to a
> message based on the address found in the From: header field. Keys in
> this table vary depending on the type of table used;
> ...
>
> For all other database types, the full user@host is checked first,
> then simply host, then user@.domain (with all superdomains checked in
> sequence, so "`foo.example.com`" would first check
> "`user@foo.example.com`", then "`user@.example.com`", then "`user@.com`"),
> then .domain, then user@*, and finally *.

---

#### Question:

> *If I wanted to be a third party ESP and offer my smtp as a service to send bulk emails, how can I automate the generation of DKIM keys and configuration for multiple clients without having to always add their domains/subdomains in all the files referenced above?*

As already answered, by using a back-end that allows an on-boarding workflow that doesn't require the manipulation of text files, but for example only the creation of new database records.

DKIM requires that domain owners add one or more specific DNS records to their domain data. That is unavoidable.

- One method is that for each domain that signs up with you generate a unique cryptographic key pair and require that the **domain owner adds the corresponding public key as a DKIM  DNS record** to their DNS zone.
  **Benefit:** You sign e-mail messages with a unique private key for  each customer.
  **Disadvantage:** You can't rotate those keys without your customer making the corresponding changes to their DNS zone.
- More convenient is that you require that the **domain owner adds DNS CNAME records** rather than an actual DKIM record to their DNS zone. That CNAME record then points to a DKIM record in your DNS zone, granting you full control and full responsibility.

  - You can have all your customers add CNAME records that point to the same DKIM TXT records in your DNS zone.
    **Benefit:** Fewer DNS records and key pairs to maintain and safeguard.
    **Disadvantage:** More fragile security with only 1 secret protecting all your customers.
    For example:

    ```
    hbruijn-1._domainkey.yourdomain. IN CNAME  dkim-1.domainkey.hbruijn.example.
    hbruijn-2._domainkey.yourdomain. IN CNAME  dkim-2.domainkey.hbruijn.example.
    ```
  - You can generate unique DKIM TXT records for each new subscriber that they will need to point their CNAME records to. (Requires a DNS solution with an API that allows you to easily create new DKIM DNS records for each new customer.)
    **Benefit:** More robust security with 1 secret protecting only a single one of your customers.
    **Disadvantage:**  More complexity with DNS records and key pairs to maintain and safeguard.
    For example:

    ```
    hbruijn-1._domainkey.yourdomain. IN CNAME  hbruijn-1.domainkey.unique-customer-ID.hbruijn.example.
    hbruijn-2._domainkey.yourdomain. IN CNAME  hbruijn-2.domainkey.unique-customer-ID.hbruijn.example.
    ```

That will allow you to start signing mail messages with selector and private key `hbruijn #1`. Then after say 6 months generate a new DKIM key pair, store that as key `hbruijn #2` , update the #2 DNS record and and after some time to allow cached DNS records to expire, re-configure OpenDKIM to start signing with key #2.

After another six months (or more frequently if you so desire) generate another new key pair but store that as key #1 overwriting the old record, update the #1 DNS record and re-configure OpenDKIM to start signing with key #1.

(When all your customers use the same CNAME target, that can almost even be done manually. Unique key pairs and DNS records per customer require an automated workflow.)

Answer (score 0):

Although I cannot answer all the questions, I ran into a similar problem some years back and created a simple BASH script which did most of the work for me. It is, however, very specific to MY setup, so if it's of any use, you'd have to tweak it to work with yours...
My scenario was rspam + PowerDNS(self-hosted). The script is commented to explain what I was doing as I went along.
You could add as many domains or subdomains as you want to the HEREDOC.

Most specifically, I am NOT a programmer, so my code is UGLY and patchy - sorry. You'd also have to run it using copy/paste a section at a time

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#START HERE#
cat << HEREDOC >mailDomains
domain1.com
domain2.org
HEREDOC

cat mailDomains; #4DBG#

fileToCreate="dnsCommandsToRun.sh";
dkimKeysBasePath="/var/lib/rspamd/dkim";
while read -r wmDomain; do
  chown _rspamd:_rspamd "$dkimKeysBasePath";
  dkimDate=$(date +%Y%m%d01); echo "$dkimDate";
  rspamadm dkim_keygen -d "$wmDomain" -s "$dkimDate" -k "${dkimKeysBasePath}/${wmDomain}.${dkimDate}.key" > "${dkimKeysBasePath}/${wmDomain}.${dkimDate}.pub";

  # We create the private_key directly into the subdir where rspam will access/use it, and the public_key to a separate file that we can use to populate the DNS
  cat "${dkimKeysBasePath}/${wmDomain}.${dkimDate}.key" "${dkimKeysBasePath}/${wmDomain}.${dkimDate}.pub";  #4DBG#

  cp "${dkimKeysBasePath}/${wmDomain}.${dkimDate}.pub" "${dkimKeysBasePath}/${wmDomain}.${dkimDate}.pub.DNS";   #Adjust the public key so you can add it to the DNS
    # Clean up the record to make the insertion into DNS manager easier
    perl -0pe 's/^(.*?)\( (.*?)\).*?$/$2/gms' -i "${dkimKeysBasePath}/${wmDomain}.${dkimDate}.pub.DNS";
    perl -0pe 's/\"\n.*?\"//gms' -i "${dkimKeysBasePath}/${wmDomain}.${dkimDate}.pub.DNS";
    perl -pe "s|\"(.*?)\".*?$|\$1|g" -i "${dkimKeysBasePath}/${wmDomain}.${dkimDate}.pub.DNS";
    dkimPDNS=$(cat "${dkimKeysBasePath}/${wmDomain}.${dkimDate}.pub.DNS";);
  commandDKIM="pdnsutil add-record $wmDomain $dkimDate._domainkey TXT 3600 \\\"\"$dkimPDNS\"\\\"";
  printf "#DKIM record\n" >> "$fileToCreate";
  echo "$commandDKIM" >> "$fileToCreate";
cat <<EOF >> /etc/rspamd/dkim_selectors.map
$wmDomain $dkimDate
EOF
done <mailDomains

cat "$fileToCreate";
chmod 700 "$fileToCreate";
sh "$fileToCreate";

cat /etc/rspamd/dkim_selectors.map

chown _rspamd:_rspamd "$dkimKeysBasePath";
chown _rspamd:_rspamd "${dkimKeysBasePath}"/*;
chown _rspamd /var/lib/rspamd/dkim/*;
chmod u=r,go= /var/lib/rspamd/dkim/*;
ls -latr "$dkimKeysBasePath"

#!to verify - AFTER you have set that up on your DNS machine and BEFORE you try to sign mails.
clear;
while read -r wmDomain; do
  printf "\n### %s""$wmDomain\n"
  newDKIM=$(grep "p=" "$dkimKeysBasePath/$wmDomain.$dkimDate.pub" | perl -pe "s/^.*?p=//g" | sed "s/\".*//");  printf "%s\n" "$newDKIM";
  digDKIM=$(dig @8.8.8.8 +short +answer TXT "${dkimDate}._domainkey.${wmDomain}"  | perl -pe "s/^.*?p=//g" | sed "s/\".*//");  printf "%s\n" "$digDKIM";
  if [ "$newDKIM" == "$digDKIM" ]; then
    printf "saved DKIM matches lookup - you should be OK to proceed\n";
    rm -f "${dkimKeysBasePath}/${wmDomain}.${dkimDate}.pub.DNS";  #Once you are sure it works
  else
    printf "saved DKIM does NOT match - something went horribly wrong\n";
  fi;
done <mailDomains

# make sure your DNS servers are in sync and then...
systemctl restart rspamd
```

Comment: I fixed some common errors from the scripts. Hopefully it still does what you expect. Instead of hard-coding the domains to the scripts, such automation might better read the list from stdin.

Comment: Thanks Esa - I have been meaning to shellcheck this for ages, but haven't gotten around to it - much obliged!
At the time of creation I was still manually adding bits & pieces, hence the hardcoded start point. 
I would now do a find -type d from my $certPath... or a pdns-list to get the domain list into an array and process that way, but I left it as a simple list so that the original poster could just add all his subdomains there if he wanted.
It could very easily be a `readarray -td '' subdomains < <(find "${pathToList}" -type f -name "subdomains.list" -print0);`

Comment: Or simply use it as `script.sh < path/to/list` with a `while read -r line` loop.